# Cannot display a JSTL Value into input field - Spring MVC

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, input

I have this value **${agact.ppr}** that i want to show in my page jsp. It can be shown like this easly:

```
<c:out value="${agact.ppr}" />
```

but I want to use it into input form like this:

```
<form:input type="text" value="${agact.ppr}" path="ppr" />
```

but it's not working I don't know why. I displayed others attributes in input fields without problem and this one no.

My class is like this :

```
Class Agent{

   int ppr;
/** setters and getters**/

}
```

Comment: Is your `form:input` tag within a `form:form` one? If yes, has you `form:form` tag a `modelAttribute` attribute already?

Comment: Yes I have all of that. I can show other attrbiute of the class easly but i don't know what is the matter with this one.

Comment: Can't you put the `Agent` instance as a property of the bean used in the `modelAttribute` attribute? For example, if your `modelAttribute` value is `myBean`, you could then use `<form:input path="myBean.agact.ppr" />`.

Comment: No, because i can show other attributes without calling the bean.

Comment: The `ppr` value in the `path` attribute refers to a property of the bean in the `modelAttribute` attribute?

Comment: Yes! look, I have two classes, all of them have 3 same attributes , I show them easly bye <c:out /> in a div for example in top of page ( without modelattribute or commandName) and in input filed into a form with commandName = the second class. so 2 attributes can display and ppr no ! I wish you get what i want to say.

Comment: I want to input this value into an input field to insert it to database. is there any other method to do it without input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the 'value' attribute, 'path' should be all you need there. Also make sure the getter and setter are valid.